# Changing port on WAMP Server

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp, serve

OK, I have a WAMP Server that I have changed the port from 80 to 7080 in the httpd.conf, but now I have an issue where when I go to the localhost it comes up blank.

To actually get the content I want to see I have to go to localhost:7080.

How can I change it so when I go to localhost without the port number and it displays the content I want to see.

I have been trying to resolve this for the best part of the day, literally around 12 hours now and I am still at a loss as to how to resolve this so any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Whats wrong with port 80?

Comment: It's already being used by other things that I don't want to remove. The WAMP icon was just stuck on red or orange, not green

Answer (score 0):

You can add 127.0.0.1:7080 mylocalhost to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host file and use mylocalhost as url link,

If you changed port from 80 to 7080, you must use it in browser to load your WAMP server.

I hope it will help.

Comment: I've decided not to mess about too much. Would be nice just to go to localhost, I did make the suggested changes but still had to use :7080. I am only using as a test bed so not vital